# What is the difference between a Constant LegacyBidirectionalIterator to value_type and a LegacyBidirectionalIterator to const value_type?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer

When looking up the type of `std::set`'s member type `iterator` I was expecting a bidirectional iterator to its `value_type const`. However, according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) it has the following member types:

| Member type | Definition |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| iterator | Constant *LegacyBidirectionalIterator* to value_type |
| const_iterator | *LegacyBidirectionalIterator* to const value_type |
| ... | ... |

In practice both are likely to be the same type, but **what is the definitional difference between these formulations?**

[*LegacyForwardIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) (which is a base of *LegacyBidirectionalIterator*) seems to differentiate between *LegacyForwardIterator* and **mutable** *LegacyForwardIterator* implying the the former is somehow not mutable, i.e. const. However [std::forward_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) references also *LegacyForwardIterator* without mention of the word mutable:

| Member type | Definition |
| --- | --- |
| iterator | LegacyForwardIterator to value_type |

Is cppreference incomplete or wrong on this account or what is going on? What is the difference between "Constant *LegacyBidirectionalIterator* to value_type" and "*LegacyBidirectionalIterator* to const value_type"?

Comment: Sparked by trying to answer [Why range based for loop doesn't work with iterator, which points to container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74925546/430766).

Answer (score 0):

> what is the definitional difference between these formulations?

From my point of view, there's little difference. The sayings are to be consistent with the descriptions of member types of other containers. i.e. `iterator` refers to `xxxIterator` to `value_type`, and `const_iterator` refers to `xxxIterator` to `const value_type`(it's already implicitly constant). e.g. [`std::map`].(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map#Member_types), [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types)

The extra **Constant** in `std::set::iterator` comes from [associative.reqmts#general-6](https://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#general-6.sentence-2)

> For associative containers where the value type is the same as the key type, both iterator and const_­iterator are constant iterators. It is unspecified whether or not iterator and const_­iterator are the same type.

Since it's mentioned these two member types are not necessarily to be the same, it's totally fine for cppref to make such literally different wordings (although it's usually the same, also mentioned by [`std::set::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin))

As to the word **mutable**, an iterator is either constant or mutable. It's used only when really necessary, so it doesn't mean an iterator without a leading mutable is constant.